# How to read (x,y) positions from any extension of vector files?

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x

I need to read all (x,y) position of a object in vector files. Is there any solution in python or nodejs?

Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you atleast provide a minimal reproducible sample of your Vector?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I need it for laser cutting.
I have a vector image files, I need to calculate how much material needed, and how much time will put cutting etc. for this I need to get the all vertices of objects in that vector files.

Comment: Well this question is too broad to answer without any sample file, do you have an example vector image file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vq8alJH0K9UGqwqeetNDyOdgCPqXRMTK/view 
Please check this link